# TYPO3: Duplicate content elements and fields after Flux 6.0.x update

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, flux, fedext

Since updating from Flux 6.0.2 to the newest Flux TER-Release (7.0.0) I have the problem that all my defined flux:field.select items are switched. I have them defined as an array like this items="{0: {0: 'value shown as a CSS class in the frontend',1: 'value shown in BE'},}". But now I get the BE value in the frontend template.

Also all my content elements from my provider extension are shown twice (without a title) in the backend and the fields defined in the 'Configuration' section of my content element are shown twice.

There's also a RTE field shown at the bottom of my content element that has not been there before.

BE Output: [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSskW.png)

Code on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CNcphn2k

Any help deeply appreciated.

EDIT:
I just set up a fresh instance of TYPO3 6.1.9 (blank package) and installed my extension with the above mentioned content elements. Dependencies were resolved automatically as it should (newest versions). Via the content wizard I tried to create a new element and I get the same result as in my existing install I first noticed this bug in.

EDIT2:
I was able to narrow it down to the flux:form.container tag. This duplicates the output in the BE. The select values are still switched though.

Comment: Did you clear all caches, including systems caches, like the extbase caches?

Comment: Yes, caches were cleared. In the BE as well as in the database.

Comment: I have no idea, please contact the author or ask in the newsgroup/mailinglist/forum.

Comment: Issue on Git: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/577

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you missed this official announcement:

http://fluidtypo3.org/blog/news/new-colpos-value.html

Failure to run the update script before letting TYPO3 change the type of the colPos value will result in the symptoms you describe. There is, unfortunately, no way to restore this (since your SQL will have cropped off all negative values and made them zero without any backup).

Restore from a backup and run the script and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Claus! First of all thank you for you answer.
I am still running TYPO3 6.1.9 and started the migration script after updating to the new version of Flux. My colPos fields in the tt_content table are updated to 18181 but still no luck.